how do I set alias for kill multiple process?
I have a command lets say cmd1 which takes only one argument at a time, something like cmd1 arg1. Now I have multiple arguments arg1,arg2,arg3...etc which should go one by one to cmd1.
I want to create one aliase in ~/.aliase such that if I give cmd2 arg1 arg2 arg3 .... it to execute
cmd1 arg1
cmd1 arg2
cmd1 arg3
cmd1 arg4 ..... 


Use pkill instead

@DiegoTorresMilano updated my question, please take a look

Your title says, you want to kill processes, but your question states that you want to run a command multiple times with different arguments. Please clarify what exactly is your problem and maybe adjust the title.

Using GNU Parallel like this parallel cmd1 ::: arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 you can run the same command parallel without the command waiting for the previous instance to finish. That way, you're using your hardware more efficient.

If you need to run them serially, then xargs is the tool instead of parallel.

Always remember the important line that's been in the Bash documentation since before 1996:

For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.

I strongly suspect "almost every" was just someone hedging their bets.  There hasn't been a reason to use an alias for decades.  As to writing a function to do what you want, it is trivial:
cmd2() { for x; do cmd1 "$x"; done; }


can I add this to ~/.aliases file and use cmd2 arg1 arg2 arg3 ...

@sachin You need that function definition somewhere.  If you have a file named .aliases that is read by your interactive shell when starting up, then putting the definition there should work.

If you don't have much infrastructure in the way of dotfiles, then you probably just want to put the function definition in .bashrc.
